# applicationWillEnterForeground load the main viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, viewcontroller

Any of you knows how can I show the main view controller when comes back form foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is very application dependent, Juan... we don't know what your application looks like (if it's got a tab bar controller or if it's a storyboard with segues or...).

But it sounds like you have a good sense of what you need to do.

You already know when an application comes back in the foreground via your [UIApplicationDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground%3a) gets called.

Then all you need to do next is segue back to your main view controller, or pop the navigation controller to get back to the root (main) view controller, or select the original tab in your tab bar controller.

Comment: but how do implement - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application  to lad the main view controller when you are not using storyboards?